# How to automatically select the last rolling quarter from a table with "Quarter" and "Year" being the only date columns

Tags: sql-server, date

I have a report I run once a quarter (in SQL Server Management Studio 2011) that pulls data from a table that is organized by year and by quarter. I usually manually update the query every time I run it but I want to try and make it as automated as possible for future users.

Here is the code I am currently using to select the required date range:

```
WHERE
    (CASE
        WHEN AN.[Year] = 2016 AND AN.[Quarter] IN (1,2) THEN 1
        WHEN AN.[Year] = 2015 AND AN.[Quarter] IN (3,4) THEN 1
        ELSE 0 END) = 1
```

So every quarter I run the query I manually update all of the where clauses to reflect the required date range.

I also need to pull data for rolling 3 years and the prior year quarter. Here is what I'm currently using for those:

```
WHERE
    (CASE
        WHEN Al.[Year] = 2016 AND Al.[Quarter] IN (1,2) THEN 1
        WHEN Al.[Year] IN (2014,2015) THEN 1
        WHEN Al.[Year] = 2013 AND Al.[Quarter] in (3,4) THEN 1
        ELSE 0 END) = 1

WHERE
    (CASE
        WHEN AN.[Year] = 2015 AND AN.[Quarter] = 2 THEN 1
        ELSE 0 END) = 1
```

Is there a way to automate this so that someone could just open the query, hit execute, and get the data for the required date ranges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the current year and current quarter to your advantage by utilizing [DATEPART](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=TSQL+DATEPART).  This query below can be built out for as many years as you need

```
DECLARE @tblDates TABLE
    (
    Dt Date,
    [Year] int,
    [Quarter] int
    )

--Identify the boundary condition
DECLARE @CurrentQuarter INT
SET @CurrentQuarter = (SELECT DATEPART(QQ, GETDATE()))

--Add in some test data
INSERT INTO @tblDates 
    SELECT GETDATE(), DATEPART(YY, GETDATE()), DATEPART(QQ, GETDATE())
    UNION SELECT DATEADD(QQ, -1, GETDATE()), DATEPART(YY, DATEADD(QQ, -1, GETDATE())), DATEPART(QQ, DATEADD(QQ, -1, GETDATE()))
    UNION SELECT DATEADD(QQ, -2, GETDATE()), DATEPART(YY, DATEADD(QQ, -2, GETDATE())), DATEPART(QQ, DATEADD(QQ, -2, GETDATE()))
    UNION SELECT DATEADD(QQ, -3, GETDATE()), DATEPART(YY, DATEADD(QQ, -3, GETDATE())), DATEPART(QQ, DATEADD(QQ, -3, GETDATE()))
    UNION SELECT DATEADD(QQ, -4, GETDATE()), DATEPART(YY, DATEADD(QQ, -4, GETDATE())), DATEPART(QQ, DATEADD(QQ, -4, GETDATE()))
    UNION SELECT DATEADD(QQ, -5, GETDATE()), DATEPART(YY, DATEADD(QQ, -5, GETDATE())), DATEPART(QQ, DATEADD(QQ, -5, GETDATE()))
    UNION SELECT DATEADD(QQ, -6, GETDATE()), DATEPART(YY, DATEADD(QQ, -6, GETDATE())), DATEPART(QQ, DATEADD(QQ, -6, GETDATE()))
    UNION SELECT DATEADD(QQ, -7, GETDATE()), DATEPART(YY, DATEADD(QQ, -7, GETDATE())), DATEPART(QQ, DATEADD(QQ, -7, GETDATE()))


SELECT * FROM @tblDates
    WHERE 
        (
        --This year, but prior to the current quarter
        [Year] = DATEPART(YY, GETDATE()) AND [Quarter] < @CurrentQuarter
        )
        OR
        (
        --Last year, but greater than or equal to current quarter will book-end the last 4 quarters
        [Year] = DATEPART(YY, GETDATE()) - 1 AND [Quarter] >=@CurrentQuarter
        )
```